# Chromium on Ubuntu doesn't resolve .local address though other applications do

Tags: networking, ubuntu, google-chrome, dns, chromium

I've got [avahi-daemon](https://linux.die.net/man/8/avahi-daemon) running on a server on my LAN with a website at `:8080`.

From my development laptop, running Ubuntu 18.04, I can get

```
brandon@arturo:~ $ ping myserver.local
PING myserver.local (192.168.1.89) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.89 (192.168.1.89): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.23 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.89 (192.168.1.89): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.20 ms
```

So `ping` is resolving the address. I get my website if I go to `myserver.local:8080` in Firefox on my development machine. The other computers in my office, running Windows and Mac, all seem to be able to access it at that address as well.

In Chromium on my laptop, if I navigate to `192.168.1.89:8080` I get my website. But if I navigate to `myserver.local:8080` I get

> myserver.local’s server IP address
>   could not be found.
>
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

What's wrong with Ubuntu Chromium?

Comment: There is no ubuntu chrome.

Comment: Whoops, I meant Chromium. Fixed.

Comment: Where are you getting “myserver.local” from? What is hosting the zone .local? Do you have a local DNS server setup or something? While it would probably work if configured properly, “myserver.local” does not look right and is not how this is usually done. Typically you would have a DNS server on your network hosting a domain (i.e. home.local) and that DNS server would hold all the records for your network devices (i.e. myserver.home.local). But you appear to be addressing your server as if it is part of the top-level domain .local. So what’s hosting the zone .local on your network?

Comment: Avahi is a zeroconf implementation, like Bonjour from Apple. It uses mDNS. Like I said, it's working just fine, as expected, from all other computers running all other browsers, and even from Firefox on my Ubuntu machine. The problem is only occurring with Chromium on Ubuntu.

Comment: chromium should be following the settings in /etc/nsswitch.conf telling it to use mdns (probably mdns4_minimal). Maybe it doesn't

Comment: My `/etc/nsswitch.conf` has the line `hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am running Ubuntu 18 and have the same issue. Firefox runs fine.

Comment: Nope, nothing yet. Please do upvote the question to help it get more visibility. It seems like people have given up on answering it (though I'm thankful for the attempt by @A.B )

Comment: @brandones but you didn't react as expected to my comment. Did you check, using tcpdump, that when using Chromium a mdns request is done (to [224.0.0.251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS#Packet_structure) port 5353)? Then that a reply happens?

Comment: Pure speculation, but could this be to do with the Chromium package being somewhat sandboxed in because of being a Snap package?

I am suffering from the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04, but unfortunately there is no simple way to install chromium without using the snap package so cannot easily test my theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because chromium on ubuntu is a snap package, which handles dns differently from the base OS.

A simple workaround is to install nscd

```
sudo apt install nscd
```

Then reboot your machine.

Comment: I'm not able to try this out any more, but I'm going to mark as answer anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 as well and I was having the same problem, I tried a bunch of things but installing chromium-browser from terminal did it for me (sudo apt install chromium-browser), and for some reason now I have 2 installed (I'm guessing one of the packages is just called chromium and this one won't resolve .local).

I end up with chromium-browser Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit)

Worth a shot.

Comment: This will no longer work for ubuntu 20.04+ as chromium can only be installed as a snap, and all snap packages suffer from this issue.